# Internet Explorer - Registering an Application to a URL Protocol after Security Update

Tags: security, internet-explorer, url, protocols, updates

As noted in [Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

***registered URL protocol vs. Security Update***

It seems, that the Kumulatives Sicherheitsupdate für Internet Explorer (2744842) http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/security/bulletin/ms12-052 supresses the using of the registered URL protocol.

Before Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox and Chrome handled such urls in the right way: calling the registered application.

Now Internet Explorer refuses the url, while Mozilla Firefox and Chrome are working properly!

*Does anyone knows how to handle it, please?*

Answer (score 0):

The ways to avoid errors are...

1. add your URL protcol site as IE's trusted site (Internet option).
2. diable safe mode of Internet zone (Internet option).
3. edit registory.

Especially about 3, you need to change

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\ProtocolDefaults]
```

you need to add your own URI scheme information like

```
"newurl"=dword:00000001
```

the above means that the URL of "newurl" is treated as intranet.
If you want "newurl" is treated as trusted sites, like

```
"newurl"=dword:00000002
```

Comment: For Windows Server 2008, it's often impossible to run 'newurl' after editing registory.
In such case, you need to configure IE ESC(Enhansed Security Setting) settings. In my case, when turning off ESC function, 'newurl' runs.